# Running apps while training models

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, deep-learning

So I'm new to deep learning (have not yet built a machine for it) and would like to know - is it possible to run other apps in Ubuntu while training a model? In particular, can I play a game in Dosbox while I'm waiting for the training to finish? It looks like there's a way to reserve one CPU core and part of the GPU via Tensorflow, but there doesn't seem to be any such functionality for RAM. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You don't need to build a dedicated machine to experiment with deep learning. There are plenty of options in the cloud, and the CPU can get you pretty far with the toy datasets that most tutorial websites and introductory courses use.

> In particular, can I play a game in Dosbox while I'm waiting for the training to finish?

There is no way I could answer this without more details. It would depend on several factors:

- Your mini-batch size during training.
- How much RAM your system has.
- If you are training on the GPU or the GPU.
- Your hard drive configuration (is your dataset on a separate drive from the OS).
- Your hard drive transfer rates and form factor (SSD vs HSSD vs NAS vs HDD).
- The number of PCIe lanes on your motherboard.
- The compatibility of your CPU with said PCIe lanes.
- The cooling capacity of your system (both CPU and GPU) and any throttling settings you have enabled.
- And probably about a dozen other variables I could name off the top of my head.

> It looks like there's a way to reserve one CPU core and part of the GPU via Tensorflow, but there doesn't seem to be any such functionality for RAM. Is there any way around that?

There are lots of ways around this. The first that comes to mind is simply decrease the batch size during training, this will decrease your RAM usage and the OS will be free to re-allocate it for your gaming needs. Another solution is to decrease the number of asynchronous threads you are using with your data loaders, to similar effect.

Do note that if your data set is large enough, you won't be using much RAM during training. Most of your computational time will be spent performing backprop on the GPU. There will be some RAM usage as training samples are DMA fed to the GPU, but you are more likely to have your gaming interfered with by utilizing so much of your GPU's memory and compute capacity.

For more information see:

- [A Full Hardware Guide to Deep Learning](http://timdettmers.com/2015/03/09/deep-learning-hardware-guide/)

Comment: The short answer would have been: as long as the game is not Minesweeper, there is a performance penalty for both: training and playing. It's not about the RAM. I can write a small cuda app without large memory consumption which still hogs all GPU processing power. There is **no** external way to restrict apps using only a few pieces of GPU processing power.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From Patwie's comment, it sounds like my chances are not good. I saw some "per process gpu memory fraction" option but didn't understand it, would it not work here?

I'll list my planned specs just in case: i5-8400 (16 PCIe lanes), 16 GB RAM, 240GB NVMe SSD, 1TB 7200RPM HDD, 8GB GTX 1070. All stock cooling plus three case fans. My intention is to have my datasets for the current model on the SSD, and train on the GPU only. I don't know much about throttling, and I can make the batch size as small as needed.

Comment: @Patwie You are correct, you can write a  *small* CUDA app without large memory conception which will still hog GPU processing power. But realistically speaking if you are training any significant neural network from scratch you will notice a GPU RAM increase, wouldn't you agree? It is much more efficient to have the variables in GPU RAM than normal RAM due to the transfer penalties incurred. You are correct that RAM is not a major consideration, but it still should be considered, if for no other reason than that of mini-batch loading with asynchronous threads.

Comment: @user10262608 I would recommend looking at the link I posted and reading through that. I can tell you that I have been working with transfer learning which involves fine-tuning instead of training the entire network. I am able to game while fine-tuning (but it is much less overhead than training from scratch). I have specs that are similar to yours. I do have the GTX 1080 Ti FTW3 instead of the GTX 1070. I also have an i7 instead of an i5 (but this doesn't matter as much as the number of logical cores). What MOBO are you planning on purchasing?

Comment: @user10262608 All you really need to know about throttling in this context is that the GPU has a peak temperature. If it rises above this peak temperature and your cooling system isn't ramping up to help the GPU reduce temperature, the GPU will take matters into its own hands and cap or reduce performance to avoid damage to the chip-set. The manufacturers provide the temperature ranges, you can look it up online. You want a cooling system that will keep your GPU cool enough that it never reaches that critical point where it throttles to avoid damage to itself.

Comment: My point was on playing. If there is only one GPU and the training kicks off (~90% occupancy) you see freezes. There is no playing while training. That's the point. My comment was about occupancy, not memory.

Comment: @Patwie Good point! Hey, like you said; there is always Minesweeper!

Comment: Update - Patwie is wrong. I installed everything and was able to play Dosbox while training models just fine. If there was any slowdown, it wasn't enough to bother me. Oh and the MB is MSI Z370-A Pro. Thanks!

Comment: @user10262608 Sure thing! Please mark my answer as correct if you found it to be so.